# Sklearn Pipeline and original model aren't the same answer "Fixed Output"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, joblib, tfidfvectorizer

I'm developing simple text classification for SMS and the full model will be 3 steps:

1. TextCleaning() "Custom function"
2. TfidfVectorizer() "Vectorizer"
3. MultinomialNB() "Classification model"

I wanted to merge the 3 steps in one model using `sklearn.pipeline` and save the model using `joblib.dump`, The problem is when load the saved model the output is **fixed** every time with any test or training data of **spam** class I got **ham**!

This is the custom function before `Pipeline` :

```
def TextCleaning(X):
    documents = []
    
    for sent in X:
        # Remove all single characters
        sent = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', sent)
        
        # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
        sent = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sent, flags=re.I)
        
        doc = nlp(sent)
        
        document = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]
        
        document = ' '.join(document)
        
        documents.append(document)
    return documents
```

This is the coded of **TextCleaning** as a **class** for `Pipeline` :

```
class TextCleaning():
    def __init__(self):
        print("call init")
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        documents = []
        for sent in X:
            # Remove all single characters
            sent = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', sent)

            # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
            sent = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sent, flags=re.I)

            doc = nlp(sent)

            document = [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

            document = ' '.join(document)

            documents.append(document)
            
        return documents
```

This is `Pipeline` code :

```
EmailClassification = Pipeline([('TextCleaning', TextCleaning()),
                                ('Vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=STOP_WORDS)),
                                ('NB', MultinomialNB())])
```

The full notebook and data on Github [Ham-or-Spam-SMS-Classification](https://github.com/abdelrahmanzied/Ham-or-Spam-SMS-Classification)

Comment: Does the saved-then-loaded pipeline make _different_ predictions than if you make the predictions in the same python instance where you trained it?  That is, is this a problem with the saving and loading, or the pipeline itself?

Comment: The first, the pipeline gave another result than the original trained model, that may happen because the training isn't the constant process, but the problem is when gave negative labeled from training data it gives a positive and any data gave the same output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notebook, you are doing:

```
EmailClassification.predict("Congratulations, you won @ free rolex")
```

If you just provide your data as a string, the Pipeline will interpret it as a list of characters and try to predict each character, hence you get the same number of predictions as the length of your string:

```
EmailClassification.predict("Congratulations, you won @ free rolex")
array(['ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham', 'ham',
       'ham'], dtype='<U4')
```

It should be:

```
EmailClassification.predict(["Congratulations, you won @ free rolex"])
array(['spam'], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the explanation of why it gives me an array of classes not a single output, I missed passing it as an element in a list.